# Will hibernating an undergoing bitlocker encryption, damage the drive?

Tags: windows-7, disk-encryption, bitlocker

Yesterday, I began encrypting a 500GB harddisk. Now I have to go to college and during my absense, I want to hibernate an undergoing bitlocker encryption. But I want to know if this is going to create problem on my harddisk.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, it will pick up where it left off.

> What happens if the computer is turned off during encryption or decryption?
>
> The BitLocker encryption and
>   decryption processes can be
>   interrupted by turning the computer
>   off, and it will resume where it left
>   off the next time Windows starts. This
>   is true even if the power is suddenly
>   unavailable.

Source: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766200%28WS.10%29.aspx

Comment: I stand *partially* corrected.

Comment: What if there is a sudden power cut

Answer (score 0):

I think not, but pause it first to be sure. I'm pretty sure there's an option to pause on whole volume encryption as well as removable drive encryption.